# javascript unicode base64 encode

Tags: javascript, powershell, unicode, base64, encode

I'm trying to convert a string to unicode and then base64 encode it in javascript but can't seem to find out how. I need it to encode my PowerShell commands so i can use -EncodedCommand command line parameter in my VMware Orchestrator project.

```
$cmd = 'New-Item -Path "C:\" -Name "Test" -ItemType Directory'
$bytes = [Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($cmd)
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
```

The output looks like this: TgBlAHcALQBJAHQAZQBtACAALQBQAGEAdABoACAAIgBDADoAXAAiACAALQBOAGEAbQBlACAAIgBUAGUAcwB0ACIAIAAtAEkAdABlAG0AVAB5AHAAZQAgAEQAaQByAGUAYwB0AG8AcgB5AA==

How can I do this in javascript?

Comment: _JavaScript_ doesn't really let you choose encodings for _String_.. I can achieve `TmV3LUl0ZW0gLVBhdGggIkM6XCIgLU5hbWUgIlRlc3QiIC1JdGVtVHlwZSBEaXJlY3Rvcnk=`

Comment: I get the same output with UTF8 but i need it in Unicode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can use [`String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode), you can re-build the *String* to contain the zero-bytes (i.e. use *String* for binary data) and then encode that as *Base64*.

```
var cmd = 'New-Item -Path "C:\\" -Name "Test" -ItemType Directory',
    ar = new Array(cmd.length * 2),
    i, j, s, b64;
// build array of bytes
for (i = 0, j = 0; i < cmd.length; j = 2 * ++i)
    ar[j] = cmd.charCodeAt(i);
// build string from array
s = String.fromCharCode.apply(String, ar);
// to base64
b64 = btoa(s);
```

This method avoids needing *Blob*, *FileReader* or an async method.

---

Just wrote a library for converting binary data between *base64*, *base16*, *base8* and *base6*, and for converting *utf8* and *utf16* between them, too. These functions all work with *Array*, *ArrayBuffer* and *Uint?Array*, with the exception of `Conv86.utfX.toY` *functions* which take *String*.

```
var Conv86 = (function () {
    var chars = (
            'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' +
            'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' +
            '0123456789+/'
        ),
        inver = {}, i;
    for (i = 0; i < chars.length; ++i) {
        inver[chars[i]] = i;
    }
    function base8To6(arr8) {
        var arr6 = [], i,
            e1, e2, e3,
            s1, s2, s3, s4,
            d1, d2, d3;
        for (i = 0; i < arr8.length; i += 3) {
            e1 = (d1 = arr8[i]    ) & 255;
            e2 = (d2 = arr8[i + 1]) & 255;
            e3 = (d3 = arr8[i + 2]) & 255;
            // wwwwwwxx xxxxyyyy yyzzzzzz
            s1 =                     e1 >>> 2 ;
            s2 = ((e1 &  3) << 4) + (e2 >>> 4);
            s3 = ((e2 & 15) << 2) + (e3 >>> 6);
            s4 =   e3 & 63                    ;
            arr6.push(s1, s2);
            if (d3 !== undefined)
                arr6.push(s3, s4);
            else if (d2 !== undefined)
                arr6.push(s3);
        }
        arr6.byteLength = arr8.length;
        return arr6;
    }
    function base6To8(arr6) {
        var arr8 = [], i,
            e1, e2, e3,
            s1, s2, s3, s4,
            d1, d2, d3, d4;
        for (i = 0; i < arr6.length; i += 4) {
            s1 = (d1 = arr6[i]    ) & 63;
            s2 = (d2 = arr6[i + 1]) & 63;
            s3 = (d3 = arr6[i + 2]) & 63;
            s4 = (d4 = arr6[i + 3]) & 63;
            // xxxxxx xxyyyy yyyyzz zzzzzz
            e1 = ( s1       << 2) + (s2 >>> 4);
            e2 = ((s2 & 15) << 4) + (s3 >>> 2);
            e3 = ((s3 &  3) << 6) +  s4       ;
            arr8.push(e1);
            if (d3 !== undefined)
                arr8.push(e2, e3);
            else if (d2 !== undefined )
                arr8.push(e2);
        }
        if (arr6.byteLength !== undefined)
            arr8.length = +arr6.byteLength;
        return arr8;
    }
    function base6To64(arr6) {
        var i, b64 = '';
        for (i = 0; i < arr6.length; ++i) b64 += chars.charAt(arr6[i]);
        /*if (arr6.bytesLength) {
            i = arr6.bytesLength % 3;
            if (i) ++i;
        } else */
        i = b64.length % 4;
        b64 += ['', '==', '==', '='][i];
        return b64;
    }
    function base8To64(arr8) {
        return base6To64(base8To6(arr8));
    }
    function base64To6(b64) {
        var arr6 = [],
            i = b64.length, lenMod = 0;
        while (b64.charAt(--i) === '=')
            ++lenMod;
        for (i = 0; i < b64.length - lenMod; ++i)
            arr6.push(inver[b64.charAt(i)]);
        i = b64.length & 3;
        if (i) i = 4 - i;
        i = i + b64.length;
        arr6.byteLength = 3 * i / 4 - lenMod;
        return arr6;
    }
    function base64To8(b64) {
        return base6To8(base64To6(b64));
    }
    // base16
    function base8To16(arr8) {
        var i, arr16 = [];
        for (i = 0; i < arr8.length; i = i + 2)
            arr16.push((arr8[i] << 8) + arr8[i + 1]);
        return arr16;
    }
    function base16To8(arr16) {
        var i, arr8 = [];
        for (i = 0; i < arr16.length; ++i)
            arr8.push(arr16[i] >>> 8, arr16[i] & 255);
        return arr8;
    }
    function base6To16(arr6) {
        return base8To16(base6To8(arr6));
    }
    function base16To6(arr16) {
        return base8To6(base16To8(arr16));
    }
    function base16To64(arr16) {
        return base8To64(base16To8(arr16));
    }
    function base64To16(b64) {
        return base8To16(base64To8(b64));
    }
    // from UTF8 to X
    function utf8To8(str) {
        var arr8 = [], i;
        for (i = 0; i < str.length; ++i)
            arr8.push(str.charCodeAt(i) & 255);
        return arr8;
    }
    function utf8To6(str) {
        return base8To6(utf8To8(str));
    }
    function utf8To16(str) {
        return base8To16(utf8To8(str));
    }
    function utf8To64(str) {
        return base8To64(utf8To8(str));
    }
    // from X to UTF8
    function utf8From8(arr8) {
        var utf8arr = [];
        for (i = 0; i < arr8.length; ++i)
            utf8arr.push(arr8[i]);
        return String.fromCharCode.apply(String, utf8arr);
    }
    function utf8From6(arr6) {
        return utf8From8(base6To8(arr6));
    }
    function utf8From16(arr16) {
        return utf8From8(base16To8(arr16));
    }
    function utf8From64(b64) {
        return utf8From8(base64To8(b64));
    }
    // from UTF16 to X
    function utf16To16(str) {
        var arr16 = [], i, c;
        for (i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
            c = str.charCodeAt(i) & 65535;
            arr16.push(((c & 255) << 8) + (c >>> 8));
        }
        return arr16;
    }
    function utf16To8(str) {
        return base16To8(utf16To16(str));
    }
    function utf16To6(str) {
        return base16To6(utf16To16(str));
    }
    function utf16To64(str) {
        return base16To64(utf16To16(str));
    }
    // from X to UTF16
    function utf16From16(arr16) {
        var utf16arr = [];
        for (i = 0; i < arr16.length; ++i)
            utf16arr.push(((arr16[i] & 255) << 8) + (arr16[i] >>> 8));
        return String.fromCharCode.apply(String, utf16arr);
    }
    function utf16From8(arr8) {
        return utf16From16(base8To16(arr8));
    }
    function utf16From6(arr6) {
        return utf16From16(base6To16(arr6));
    }
    function utf16From64(b64) {
        return utf16From16(base64To16(b64));
    }
    return {
        base6: {
            to8: base6To8,
            to16: base6To16,
            to64: base6To64,
        },
        base8: {
            to6: base8To6,
            to16: base8To16,
            to64: base8To64
        },
        base16: {
            to6: base16To6,
            to8: base16To8,
            to64: base16To64
        },
        base64: {
            to6: base64To6,
            to8: base64To8,
            to16: base64To16
        },
        utf8: {
            to8: utf8To8,
            to6: utf8To6,
            to16: utf8To16,
            to64: utf8To64,
            from8: utf8From8,
            from6: utf8From6,
            from16: utf8From16,
            from64: utf8From64
        },
        utf16: {
            to8: utf16To8,
            to6: utf16To6,
            to16: utf16To16,
            to64: utf16To64,
            from8: utf16From8,
            from6: utf16From6,
            from16: utf16From16,
            from64: utf16From64
        }
    };
}());
```

An example usage

```
Conv86.utf16.from64(
    Conv86.utf16.to64('New-Item -Path "C:\\" -Name "Test" -ItemType Directory')
        // "TgBlAHcALQBJAHQAZQBtACAALQBQAGEAdABoACAAIgBDADoAXAAiACAALQBOAGEAbQBlACAAIgBUAGUAcwB0ACIAIAAtAEkAdABlAG0AVAB5AHAAZQAgAEQAaQByAGUAYwB0AG8AcgB5AA=="
); // "New-Item -Path "C:\" -Name "Test" -ItemType Directory"
```

Comment: Confirming that this works with the library you posted instead of `btoa`, as well.

Comment: I just tried it with the library but i get this error "TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined". Did you get it to work with the library?

Comment: Now i got it to work - i replaced b64 = btoa(s); with return b64 but as it said this was undefined. So i replaced b64 with s and now it work. Thanks a lot for the help Poul S.

Comment: There should be a warning that [*btoa*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.btoa) is not part of any standard and is not supported by many browsers in use (e.g. IE before version 10).

Comment: @RobG I only put it there because I used it to test with; was expecting OP to replace it with their library's `Base64.encode` call.

Comment: @RobG Just found _btoa_ and _atob_ in the _HTML 5.1_ draft section `6.2` http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/webappapis.html#atob

Comment: Hmmm—HTML5 isn't a standard (and never will be), it's a specification of browser behaviour that is ever–changing with no version control. Anyway, it's worth noting in an answer if something isn't part of a **standard** or may not be supported by all (say 99% of) browsers in use. IE < 10 is perhaps 15% to 20%, maybe more, depending on who you believe.

Comment: Hi Poul S.I tried your new command Conv86.utf16.to64 with the text '-Domain' (without ') and got this LQBEAG8AbQBhAGkAbgA== but in PowerShell i get this LQBEAG8AbQBhAGkAbgA= (there is an extra =)

Could there be an error in your code?

Comment: @user2628440 quite possibly! I wasn't sure about how to write the logic to add `=`s, must have got it wrong.

Comment: @user2628440 did a fix? in the place where this was being experienced; should all work now.

Answer (score 0):

If you construct a [*Blob*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) to have the encoding you want, you can then make use of [*FileReader's*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) `readAsDataURL` to build your desired output.

```
var cmd = 'New-Item -Path "C:\\" -Name "Test" -ItemType Directory',
    pad = new Uint8Array(1), // to help change to UTF-16 (?)
    ar = [],
    i,
    blob,
    fr = new FileReader();
fr.onload = function () {
    var i = this.result.indexOf(','); // trim off starting dataURI part
    console.log(this.result.slice(i + 1));
};
for (i = 0; i < cmd.length; ++i) ar.push(cmd.charAt(i)), ar.push(pad);
blob = new Blob(ar); // now contains the bytes you want
fr.readAsDataURL(blob); // async warning!
```

Will give you your desired

```
TgBlAHcALQBJAHQAZQBtACAALQBQAGEAdABoACAAIgBDADoAXAAiACAALQBOAGEAbQBlACAAIgBUAGUAcwB0ACIAIAAtAEkAdABlAG0AVAB5AHAAZQAgAEQAaQByAGUAYwB0AG8AcgB5AA==
```

Comment: It's not possible to use any browser related objects so the code you posted doesn't work. I have been trying the code from http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html but i'm not smart enough to replace the UTF8 with UTF16/Unicode instead.

Comment: I've posted a different way to tackle the same problem which doesn't need _FileReader, Blob_, etc :)